# Reset ROW_NUMBER() when previous partition ID changes

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to reset the ROW_NUMBER() value when there is a change in one of the IDs when sequenced in datetime order.
For example in the table below, when Location_ID changes, I want to reset the RowNum to 1.
Here's the statement I am using.

```
[RowNum] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EventDate, Asset_ID, Location_ID ORDER BY Scan_Timestamp)
```

I get RowNumX, but want RowNumY.

| EventDate | Scan_Timestamp | Asset_ID | Location_ID | RowNumX | RowNumY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9/1/2021 | 09/01/21 12:28 AM | 30010712 | 996 | 1 | 1 |
| 9/1/2021 | 09/01/21 06:18 AM | 30010712 | 30000372 | 1 | 1 |
| 9/1/2021 | 09/01/21 06:52 AM | 30010712 | 30000345 | 1 | 1 |
| 9/1/2021 | 09/01/21 08:43 AM | 30010712 | 996 | 2 | 1 Reset (Loc_ID changed) |
| 9/1/2021 | 09/01/21 08:44 AM | 30010712 | 996 | 3 | 2 |
| 9/1/2021 | 09/01/21 08:47 AM | 30010712 | 30000402 | 1 | 1 |
| 9/1/2021 | 09/01/21 11:17 AM | 30010712 | 996 | 4 | 1 Reset (Loc_ID changed) |
| 9/1/2021 | 09/01/21 11:17 AM | 30010712 | 997 | 1 | 1 |
| 9/1/2021 | 09/01/21 01:34 PM | 30010712 | 997 | 2 | 2 |
| 9/1/2021 | 09/01/21 01:47 PM | 30010712 | 30000402 | 2 | 1 Reset (Loc_ID changed) |
| 9/1/2021 | 09/01/21 01:51 PM | 30010712 | 997 | 3 | 1 Reset (Loc_ID changed) |
| 9/1/2021 | 09/01/21 01:52 PM | 30010712 | 997 | 4 | 2 |

I'm thinking I have to join using a CTE, but was hoping someone might see an obvious simple solution that I am overlooking.

Comment: But the results of your expression for `ROW_NUMBER` don't give the results for `RowNumX` in the table above... [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9b706058259accdb0fac2df0a877f34d) You need to explain the logic here, it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Side note, the inconsistent formatting of your dates implies you're storing them in a `varchar` column; I *hope* not.

Comment: I'm using CONVERT(date,Scan_Timestamp) for EventDate

Comment: Simply ingenious, worked perfectly! I hadn't even considered LAG(). It will be my new best friend. Thank you db<>fiddle for such a quick reply!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This is a type of gaps-and-islands problem.**

There are many solutions, here is one:

- Use `LAG` to identify rows where `LocationID` changes
- Use a windowed count to create a grouping ID for each island
- Then calculate the row-number using this grouping ID as a partitioning column

```
WITH Changes AS (
    SELECT *,
      IsChange = CASE WHEN LAG(Location_ID, 1, -999) OVER (PARTITION BY EventDate, Asset_ID
                      ORDER BY Scan_Timestamp) <> Location_ID THEN 1 END
    FROM YourTable t
),
Groups AS (
    SELECT *,
      GroupId = COUNT(IsChange) OVER (PARTITION BY EventDate, Asset_ID
                      ORDER BY Scan_Timestamp ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
    FROM Changes
)
SELECT
  EventDate,
  Scan_Timestamp,
  Asset_ID,
  Location_ID,GroupId,IsChange,
  RowNumY = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EventDate, Asset_ID, GroupId ORDER BY Scan_Timestamp)
FROM Groups;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8b96f0f9e37fac54e362d0784d372c09)

Comment: Simply ingenious, worked perfectly! I hadn't even considered LAG(). It will be my new best friend. Thank you @db<>fiddle for such a quick reply!